# tar.xz - how to check uncompressed files size without decompress whole archive

Tags: linux, gzip, tar, xz

I have a problem with checking uncompressed size from archive **tar.xz** without extract whole archive.
I know that for tar.gz I can use gzip or zcat but for tar.xz it dosnt work.

Any sugestion how to do this ?

Comment: If you want a solution similar to `zcat`, see [`man xzcat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xzcat). I suggest to [edit] your question and show what command you use for `.tar.gz`. This might clarify what exactly you mean with "checking uncompressed size".

Comment: If you mean the uncompressed size of the entire .tar archive, use `xz -lv archive.tar.xz`. If you want the uncompressed sizes of each of the files therein, see Bib's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar tvfa <file>` will give you a list including file sizes. Check `man tar` for details. You should also note, that file size does not equate to disk usage, since part of a file can take a full file system block.

Answer (score 4):

`xz -l file.xz` will give you the compressed/uncompressed sizes of the archive in a human-readable way (KiB MiB suffixes) without actually decompressing (no CPU or disk load). It won't list the files inside the tar archive, though.

`xz -lv file.xz` is verbose, and you can filter it to get the exact sizes in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer from Lucas, you can use the `--robot` flag to `xz` to script this cleanly:

```
uncomp_size=$(xz --robot --list "${local_file}" | grep ^totals | cut -f5)
```